# Query by distance in ArcGIS rest service to check if a point is within a buffer of a feature

Tags: javascript, json, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, mapserver

Let me start out by saying: *distance and units are not available fields in this query.*

**Desired Outcome:** I want to return the feature (or a count: 1) when a point is queried within 10 miles (or otherwise any specified distance) of that feature. I want this returned in a JSON to use as an API in JavaScript.

I've tried messing with the "query by distance" field but am not sure if that is correct and I am not getting desired results.

For what I'm doing, I want to check if a point is within a 10 mile radius of a CBRS unit.

[Link to the Query in question](https://cbrsgis.wim.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/CoastalBarrierResourcesSystem/MapServer/3/query)

As you can see, distance and units are not available fields - so the documentation on this is no help.

Here is the top half of the query with the options I have tried. The coordinates I have selected here are in close proximity, but not within a CBRS unit - so when this works the way I intend, something should appear. When I am getting the result I want I will eventually be checking return count as true:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZnSt.png

Coordinates I'm using for ease of copy/paste: -86.220824,44.5773

Comment: If you intend to use it within the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, why not use that API's Query class instead of trying to send a direct request to the REST endpoint of the service? Using the JSAPI should be easier. Or are you trying to debug something?

Comment: I am honestly unsure what you're asking as I'm relatively new to this - I am planning to run an API in JavaScript using the JSON generated from the above query link. I will put variables in place of the coordinates in the JSON link in my code in order to check if given coordinates from user input are within a certain radius of the feature. I'm not sure what alternatives I have here (besides taking the coordinates in the JS code to create a polygon around them and check that instead - I just thought this seems inefficient - no simpler way in the query?)